# Matching regex for range (1 to 99) integres and xx.xx for decimals

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need help in regex pattern were

integer should be min 1 and max 999 `/(?:^([1-9][1-9]{0,2})$)/;`

decimal should be xx.yy  => `[0-9].[0-9]`

Comment: And.... What's the problem?

Comment: for decimal it can have  zero (ex:- 0.111)

Comment: What in case of different OS settings, where decimal point is not a `.`, but `,`?

Comment: yes in ur correct

Answer (score 1):

The min-max range that you want to use is not Ok. It can not match 100 as the second and the third digit can not be 0 due to the range 1-9.

It should be `[0-9]{0,2}` or in short `\d{0,2}`

This pattern `[0-9].[0-9]` will not match only a after a dot, as the dot is not escaped `\.` So it can match any char except a newline and there is only a single digit after it to match.

To match a digit 1-999:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DimOGg/1)

For decimals (which can also start with 0)

```
^[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5d3mg/1)